# Association between three categorical variables

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, descriptive-statistics

Forgive me if this is a silly stats question.
I have three nominal variables which describe yes/no for growth of bacteria. They are three different sample types (infant, poultry and floor surface). 
They come from the same household (i.e. each household has 3 samples).
I am trying to see associations between and across households in yes/no of growth. 
It is a small sample size (35).
Any advice appreciated.
Thanks